# ¿Como llenar una columna con datos de la columna de otras 2 tablas?

Tags: insert

tengo las siguiente tablas:

**TABLA A:**

```
ID NOMBRE

1   A 

2   B 

3   C
```

y **TABLA B**:

```
ID  NOMBRE

1   D 

2   E
```

y quiero insertar los datos de las columnas "nombre" de ambas tablas en la columna "nombre" de una tercera tabla (**TABLA C**).

y que me quede algo asi:

**TABLA C**

```
ID  NOMBRE

1   A 

2   B 

3   C

4   D

5   E
```

Tengo que aclarar que las 3 Tablas tienen la misma estructura.
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Pues si sólo buscas eso entonces una opción podría ser primero pasar los valores de la tabla A a la tabla C con lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO TABLA_C(nombre) SELECT nombre FROM TABLA_A
```

Y después pasar los valores de la tabla B a la tabla C

```
INSERT INTO TABLA_C(nombre) SELECT nombre FROM TABLA_B
```

La otra opción es que hagas UNION de las tablas A y B.

Comment: Jose gracias x tu interés, precisamente quiero es evitar hacer 2 sentencias, quiero hacerlo en una sola.

Comment: #dev01 entonces sería mediante una unión (bueno esto es en SQL Server, pero de seguro hay algo parecido en otras BD), algo como esto: INSERT INTO TABLA_C(nombre) SELECT nombre FROM TABLA_A UNION ALL SELECT nombre FROM TABLA_B

Comment: Excelente Jose, era era lo que buscaba, gracias!